Plate at constant voltage and square law
I am trying to understand why or how fixing voltage instead of the charge of a plate seems to overcome the square law as if the plate was infinite. Below is an argument that illustrates the paradoxical result.
Consider a plate of finite size that is charged to some voltage with ground potential $0 V$ distance $d$ away in front of the plate. At the moment no charge is flowing.
Now, from Gauss's law
$$-\nabla \cdot \nabla V=\rho.$$
Inside the plate $V$ is constant and likewise $E$ is zero in the steady state. The charge $\rho$ must therefore be fully distributed to the boundary of the plate. Then the situation is analogous to the classic charged plate. Electric field should follow square law asymptotically as the distance increases, while an infinite plate should have fixed electric field.
Now consider the midpoint of the plate. No charge is flowing so by Gauss's law, some distance away from the plate
$$\nabla\cdot E=0,$$
therefore by symmetry
$$\partial E_x =0.$$
Hence at the midpoint $E$ must be constant between the plate and the ground potential at which it jumps to zero. But where does the charge come from to facilitate this field?

Solution: The error seems to be that $E$ is not differentiable at the mid-point rather than the perpendicular components being zero.
